# KafkaStream not receiving any messages from Topic

Tags: kafka-consumer-api, apache-kafka-connect

I'm playing around with `KafkaStreams` and `KafkaConnect` simply trying to consume messages from a topic. I have a "standard" batch consumer set up for this topic and it works like a charm. I first send a couple of records to Kafka and consume them afterwards. Now I want to do the same using Kakfa streams, but I don't get a single message from the topic. Here's the consumer code that I'm using.

```
final int NUMBER_OF_PARTITIONS = 4;
final Properties consumerConfig = new Properties();
consumerConfig.setProperty("zookeeper.connect", RULE.getConfiguration().kafka.getZookeeperUrl());
consumerConfig.setProperty("backoff.increment.ms", "100");
consumerConfig.setProperty("group.id", "java-consumer-example");
consumerConfig.setProperty("consumer.timeout.ms", "1000000");
consumerConfig.setProperty("client.id", "someclient");
consumerConfig.setProperty("auto.offset.reset", "smallest");
consumerConfig.setProperty("enable.auto.commit", "false");
consumerConfig.setProperty("bootstrap.servers", RULE.getConfiguration().kafka.getHosts());

final ConsumerConnector connector = Consumer.createJavaConsumerConnector(new ConsumerConfig(consumerConfig));
final TopicFilter sourceTopicFilter = new Whitelist(RULE.getConfiguration().kafka.getTopic());

final VerifiableProperties decoderProps = new VerifiableProperties();
decoderProps.props().setProperty("schema.registry.url", RULE.getConfiguration().kafka.getRegistry());
decoderProps.props().setProperty("max.schemas.per.subject", "1");
final List<KafkaStream<String, Object>> streams = connector
    .createMessageStreamsByFilter(sourceTopicFilter, NUMBER_OF_PARTITIONS, new StringDecoder(decoderProps), new KafkaAvroDecoder(decoderProps));

final ExecutorService executorService = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(NUMBER_OF_PARTITIONS);
for (final KafkaStream stream : streams) {
    executorService.submit(() -> {
        try {
            final ConsumerIterator it = stream.iterator();
            while (it.hasNext()) {
                final MessageAndMetadata messageAndMetadata = it.next();
                final String key = (String) messageAndMetadata.key();
                System.out.println("KEY" + key);
            }
        } catch (final Exception ex) {
            LOGGER.error("ERROR", ex);
        }
    });
}
```

My problem is, that my code keeps on waiting in the `it.hasNext()` condition until the timeout is reached. I'm probably missing some detail here, but can't figure out, why I don't get anything out of the topic. As part of this test, I have a producer that sends a number of records into this topic right before the consumer starts, so it can't be an offset problem. Any ideas would be highly welcome.

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution. The error was outside the code I posted. The timeout I provided for the shutdown of the ExecutorService was too short so it just killed it without providing enough time to do the consumer job.